# Doctrine Update -- Mysql Errno: 150

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an issue while trying to update a table. I am trying to run the follow command:

```
sudo -u www-data -H ./app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1483A5E9A35D7AF0 FOREIGN KEY (invitation_id)    REFERENCES Invitation (code);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_1483A5E9A35D7AF0 ON users (invitation_id);
```

Based on this Configuration:

```
#../Entity/Users.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Invitation", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="code")
 * @Assert\NotNull(message="Your invitation is wrong")
 */
protected $invitation;

#../Entity/Invitations.php

/** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Users", mappedBy="invitation", cascade={"persist", "merge"}) */
protected $user;
```

it gives me the error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_1483A5E9F11D61A2 FOREIGN KEY (invitation) REFERENCES Invitation (code)':
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'loopanime-mvc.#sql-402_bc3' (errno: 150)
```

Both tables are on InnoDb and the collection is ut8_unicode_ci. I didnt try to run to create the index manually because thats not what i want!! But why the hell doesnt the doctrine create first the IDX before the FK ??

How can i solve my dilema. Thank you. Sorry if the question isnt clear i cant describe more than this...

Comment: Errno 150 can be caused by differences in data type, but it can also be caused if there is data in the table that doesn't satisfy the constraint. So I would guess that you have some row(s) in `users` that reference a non-existant invitation code.

Comment: I have truncated both tables it still doesnt do the trick. If i add the Index manually and then create the FK it works. I think its a doctrine bug putting it to the last. Or there is a issue on my annotations.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Creating a foreign key should create a needed index implicitly since MySQL 4.1.2, which is an ancient historical artifact by today's standards.

Comment: Sorry Bill you were also right, its fixed check below what the problem was! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry I can't write a comment yet)
Did you check that both fields are exactly of the same type? Errno 150 generally is produced by that mistake...

Comment: I am afraid this is not the correct answer -- as i stated on the other comment i truncated both tables and still i have this issue. On doctrine if you knew by the way that i put things it would create me exactly the same key with the same types and lengths

Comment: Sorry Facundo you were right. I truncated but my column was created with DEFAULT NULL and it was missleading. Fixed thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Its fixed, it was a difference on structure. Doctrine have create the column with DEFAULT NULL probably because it already have content inside the table and the FK could not be created.

Deleting all information / putting some dumb values on column and change that DEFAULT solved the problem.

Thank you for all your support!